# A natural isomorphism $\Omega_X \to T_{X,0}^* \otimes _k \mathscr{O}_X$ on an abelian variety $X$ (and the identification of vector fields)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $X$ be an abelian variety over a field, $\Omega_X$ the differential sheaf, $\mathscr{T}_X$ the tangent sheaf, i.e., $\mathscr{Hom}(\Omega_X, \mathscr{O}_X)$, and $T_{X,0}$ be the tangent space at $0$ of $X$.
I want a natural isomorphism $\Omega_X \to T_{X,0}^* \otimes _k \mathscr{O}_X$.
($V^*$ is the dual space of a vector space $V$.)

The proposition 1.5. in http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/elenalavanda/BMoonen.pdf
proves this, but I don't understand.

He says that a vector field on $X$ (i.e., an element of $\Gamma (X, \mathscr{T}_X )$ ) can be identified with an automorphism $X_S \to X_S$ which reduces to the identity on $X$.
($S = k[x]/x^2$)

I don't understand this.

(This is a similar question to [Making rigorous Mumford's argument about the sheaf of differentials on an Abelian Variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835772/making-rigorous-mumfords-argument-about-the-sheaf-of-differentials-on-an-abelia?rq=1) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A morphism $\operatorname{Spec} S \to X$ is equivalent to a choice of a $k$-point and a tangent vector (see, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/correspondence-between-k-epsilon-epsilon2-points-of-a-scheme-and-points)). An automorphism $X_S\to X_S$ which is the identity on $X$ gives a family of morphisms $\operatorname{Spec} S \to X_S \stackrel{red}{\to} X$ indexed by the points of $X$, which can be interpreted as a family of tangent vectors at each point $x\in X$, also known as a vector field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is a family of morphism $S \to X$ indexed by points of $X$, induced by an automorphism of $X_S$?

Comment: Put another way, given an automorphism of $X_S$ reducing to the identity on $X$, for each $k$-point $x\in X$, we get a map $\operatorname{Spec} S \to X_S$ by restricting the domain of the automorphism to the $\operatorname{Spec} S$ living above $x$ in $X_S$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what this family is. And I get a family of morphisms $\Omega_x \to \mathscr{O}_x$, induced by a family of tangent vectors. But I don't understand how I glue these maps together to get a global morphism $\Omega \to \mathscr{O}$.

Comment: They're already given by a global morphism: $X_S\stackrel{Aut}{\to} X_S \stackrel{Red}{\to} X$. This map associates to each point $x\in X$ a tangent vector in the following way - for an $x\in X$, the tangent vector is obtained as the result of $S\stackrel{(x,id)}{\hookrightarrow} X_S \stackrel{Aut}{\to} X_S \stackrel{Red}{\to} X$.

Comment: I'd further recommend checking out exercise 1.3 (referenced in this proof), since it provides many of the details that the author skips over in this proof.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've understood!